# Why wouldn’t light arrive at the same time in the Michelson-Morley experiment?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, relativity

I understand that in the Michelson-Morley experiment a light source is split with a partially silvered reflector. They expected a shift in the interference pattern because they argued that the ether would slow down the light and cause it to arrive at the observer at a different time.

I am struggling to understand how this expectation makes sense. If the ether were like a river, and assuming it’s speed is constant, as the light goes with the flow of the ether it should speed up. However, then, as it is reflected back, surely it is slowed by the same amount, so both sources should arrive at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia description of [Michelson-Morley experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment) have formulae of the predicted times:

[image]

And although you are right, that forward pass will be faster and backward pass slower, the fact that the velocity enters the formula in the denominator doesn't allow to cancel out the change:
$$
\frac{L}{c-v}+\frac{L}{c+v} = L\frac{c+v+c-v}{c^2-v^2} = \frac{2L}{c-v^2/c}\neq \frac{2L}c
$$